# Task doesn't work in verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl, system-verilog

I created a module that first sorts a byte array then choose last element as minimum.(just for practice). When I moved sort to the task block, it doesn't worked as well as before. How can use task block properly for sorting ? thanks.

Sort without task:

```
    module sort(input clk, input nrst, output byte choose);

    byte sorted[0:3];

    assign choose = sorted[3];// output must be minimum after sort (12)

    always@(posedge clk, negedge nrst) begin                
        if(nrst == 0) begin // initialize to something
            sorted[0] = 17;
            sorted[1] = 12;
            sorted[2] = 23;
            sorted[3] = 21;
        end 
        else begin                      
            int i, j;               
            byte tmp;           
            //sort  
            for(i=0; i<4; i=i+1)            
                for(j=0; j<4; j=j+1)
                    if(sorted[j] < sorted[j+1]) begin
                        tmp = sorted[j]; // swap
                        sorted[j] = sorted[j+1];
                        sorted[j+1] = tmp;
                    end                                                 
        end                         
    end

endmodule
```

Sort with Task:

```
module sort(input clk, input nrst, output byte choose);

    byte sorted[0:3];

    assign choose = sorted[3];// output must be minimum after sort (12)

    always@(posedge clk, negedge nrst) begin                
        if(nrst == 0) begin // initialize to something
            sorted[0] = 17;
            sorted[1] = 12;
            sorted[2] = 23;
            sorted[3] = 21;
        end 
        else begin                      
            sort_task(sorted);                                      
        end                         
    end

    task sort_task(inout byte list[3:0]);
        begin 
            int i, j;               
            byte tmp;           
            //sort  
            for(i=0; i<4; i=i+1)            
                for(j=0; j<4; j=j+1)
                    if(list[j] < list[j+1]) begin
                        tmp = list[j];
                        list[j] = list[j+1];
                        list[j+1] = tmp;
                    end                                                 

        end
    endtask

endmodule
```

Testbench:

```
module tb();

    byte choose;
    reg nrst, clk;

    sort sort(clk, nrst, choose);

    initial begin       
        clk = 0;        
        forever #5 clk = ~clk;      
    end     

    initial begin       
        int i;
        nrst = 1;
        #50;
        for(i=0; i<4; i=i+1)            
            $display("50 : %d", sort.sorted[i]);
        nrst = 0;       
        #50
        for(i=0; i<4; i=i+1)            
            $display("100 : %d", sort.sorted[i]);               
        nrst = 1;   
        #50 
        for(i=0; i<4; i=i+1)            
            $display("150: %d", sort.sorted[i]);                
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: Task are normally reserved for testbenches and not synthesisable code. should it not return a value rather than use inouts? maybe a function is what you were wanting, except functions have to execute in zero time.

Comment: When I declare a function with return type of `byte [0:3]`(for sorted list), Modelsim give error 'can't assign unpacked...'. I didn't know how to return a list of bytes from a function, so I preferred using task. I think tasks are synthesisable as well as functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there is a mismatch in the index declaration for `sorted[0:3]` versus `list[3:0]`, so `(list[j] < list[j+1])` gives you the reverse evaluation. I strongly recommend using common typedef's (in a package) to eliminate problems like this.

```
typedef byte list_t[4];
list_t sorted;
task sort_task( inout list_t list);
```

BTW, using a typedef gives you the syntax needed to declare a function with unpacked return type because any simple name is allowed for a return type, no matter how complex the typedef is.

Also, I agree with you that a task is synthesizable, as long as the code inside the task is meets your tools synthesis modelling style. But I would prefer that people use a void function instead of a task when their task has no time consuming statements. A function is a guarantee that it will not consume time.

Comment: This is being assigned as synchronous logic, therefore non-blocking assignments (`<=`) is recommended. Blocking assignments should be used inside method to keep it portable and self-contained. I'd suggest the method header be `function list_t sort_func( input list_t list);` which returns the sorted list, and then you can assign the array as `sorted <= sort_func(shorted);`.

Comment: Thank you for your professional guidance. I was involved in this question that how can return a list from a function. Using typedef solved  it. But I don’t understand why function is better the task. I think in compile time, inner codes of the both blocks will move to the place that they called.

Comment: You will appreciate the guideline better when you start having nested calls to tasks and functions - especially when you start writing testbenches that have nested calls. Calling a function documents your intent that the call will not block, as well as any other nested call. The problem with using nested task calls is when a task deep inside your call stack has a modification that blocks - it will be very difficult to debug. Verilog did not have void functions - they always had to be used in an expression. That's why you see lots of non-time-consuming tasks.